# program for keyboard in windows

Tags: c, windows

I am writing a program for displaying all the information that the windows sends the window procedure for 8 different keyboard messages. Here is the code

```
/*--------------------------------------------------------
   KEYVIEW1.C -- Displays Keyboard and Character Messages
                 (c) Charles Petzold, 1998
  --------------------------------------------------------*/   

#include <windows.h>

    LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM) ;

    int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                        PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
    {
         static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT ("KeyView1") ;
         HWND         hwnd ;
         MSG          msg ;
         WNDCLASS     wndclass ;

         wndclass.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW ;
         wndclass.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc ;
         wndclass.cbClsExtra    = 0 ;
         wndclass.cbWndExtra    = 0 ;
         wndclass.hInstance     = hInstance ;
         wndclass.hIcon         = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION) ;
         wndclass.hCursor       = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW) ;
         wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject (WHITE_BRUSH) ;
         wndclass.lpszMenuName  = NULL ;
         wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName ;

         if (!RegisterClass (&wndclass))
         {
              MessageBox (NULL, TEXT ("This program requires Windows NT!"), 
                          szAppName, MB_ICONERROR) ;
              return 0 ;
         }

         hwnd = CreateWindow (szAppName, TEXT ("Keyboard Message Viewer #1"),
                              WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                              CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                              CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                              NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL) ;

         ShowWindow (hwnd, iCmdShow) ;
         UpdateWindow (hwnd) ;

         while (GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
         {
              TranslateMessage (&msg) ;
              DispatchMessage (&msg) ;
         }
         return msg.wParam ;
    }

    LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
         static int   cxClientMax, cyClientMax, cxClient, cyClient, cxChar, cyChar ;
         static int   cLinesMax, cLines ;
         static PMSG  pmsg ;
         static RECT  rectScroll ;
         static TCHAR szTop[] = TEXT ("Message        Key       Char     ")
                                TEXT ("Repeat Scan Ext ALT Prev Tran") ;
         static TCHAR szUnd[] = TEXT ("_______        ___       ____     ")
                                TEXT ("______ ____ ___ ___ ____ ____") ;

         static TCHAR * szFormat[2] = { 

                   TEXT ("%-13s %3d %-15s%c%6u %4d %3s %3s %4s %4s"),
                   TEXT ("%-13s            0x%04X%1s%c %6u %4d %3s %3s %4s %4s") } ;

         static TCHAR * szYes  = TEXT ("Yes") ;
         static TCHAR * szNo   = TEXT ("No") ;
         static TCHAR * szDown = TEXT ("Down") ;
         static TCHAR * szUp   = TEXT ("Up") ;

         static TCHAR * szMessage [] = { 
                             TEXT ("WM_KEYDOWN"),    TEXT ("WM_KEYUP"), 
                             TEXT ("WM_CHAR"),       TEXT ("WM_DEADCHAR"), 
                             TEXT ("WM_SYSKEYDOWN"), TEXT ("WM_SYSKEYUP"), 
                             TEXT ("WM_SYSCHAR"),    TEXT ("WM_SYSDEADCHAR") } ;
         HDC          hdc ;
         int          i, iType ;
         PAINTSTRUCT  ps ;
         TCHAR        szBuffer[128], szKeyName [32] ;
         TEXTMETRIC   tm ;

         switch (message)
         {
         case WM_CREATE:
         case WM_DISPLAYCHANGE:

                   // Get maximum size of client area

              cxClientMax = GetSystemMetrics (SM_CXMAXIMIZED) ;
              cyClientMax = GetSystemMetrics (SM_CYMAXIMIZED) ;

                  // Get character size for fixed-pitch font

              hdc = GetDC (hwnd) ;

              SelectObject (hdc, GetStockObject (SYSTEM_FIXED_FONT)) ;
              GetTextMetrics (hdc, &tm) ;
              cxChar = tm.tmAveCharWidth ;
              cyChar = tm.tmHeight ;

              ReleaseDC (hwnd, hdc) ;

                   // Allocate memory for display lines

              if (pmsg)
                   free (pmsg) ;

              cLinesMax = cyClientMax / cyChar ;
              pmsg = (PMSG)malloc (cLinesMax * sizeof (MSG)) ;
              cLines = 0 ;
                                       // fall through
         case WM_SIZE:
              if (message == WM_SIZE)
              {
                   cxClient = LOWORD (lParam) ;
                   cyClient = HIWORD (lParam) ;
              }
                   // Calculate scrolling rectangle

              rectScroll.left   = 0 ;
              rectScroll.right  = cxClient ;
              rectScroll.top    = cyChar ;
              rectScroll.bottom = cyChar * (cyClient / cyChar) ;

              InvalidateRect (hwnd, NULL, TRUE) ;
              return 0 ;

         case WM_KEYDOWN:
         case WM_KEYUP:
         case WM_CHAR:
         case WM_DEADCHAR:
         case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
         case WM_SYSKEYUP:
         case WM_SYSCHAR:
         case WM_SYSDEADCHAR: 

                   // Rearrange storage array

              for (i = cLinesMax - 1 ; i > 0 ; i--)
              {
                   pmsg[i] = pmsg[i - 1] ;
              }
                   // Store new message

              pmsg[0].hwnd = hwnd ;
              pmsg[0].message = message ;
              pmsg[0].wParam = wParam ;
              pmsg[0].lParam = lParam ;

              cLines = min (cLines + 1, cLinesMax) ;

                   // Scroll up the display

              ScrollWindow (hwnd, 0, -cyChar, &rectScroll, &rectScroll) ;

              break ;        // ie, call DefWindowProc so Sys messages work

         case WM_PAINT:
              hdc = BeginPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;

              SelectObject (hdc, GetStockObject (SYSTEM_FIXED_FONT)) ;
              SetBkMode (hdc, TRANSPARENT) ;
              TextOut (hdc, 0, 0, szTop, lstrlen (szTop)) ;
              TextOut (hdc, 0, 0, szUnd, lstrlen (szUnd)) ;

              for (i = 1 ; i < max (cLines, cyClient / cyChar - 1) ; i++)
              {
                   iType = pmsg[i].message == WM_CHAR ||
                           pmsg[i].message == WM_SYSCHAR ||
                           pmsg[i].message == WM_DEADCHAR ||
                           pmsg[i].message == WM_SYSDEADCHAR ;

                   GetKeyNameText (pmsg[i].lParam, szKeyName, 
                                   sizeof (szKeyName) / sizeof (TCHAR)) ;

                   TextOut (hdc, 0, (cyClient / cyChar -  i) * cyChar, szBuffer,
                            wsprintf (szBuffer, szFormat [iType],
                                 szMessage [pmsg[i].message - WM_KEYFIRST],                   
                                 pmsg[i].wParam,
                                 (PTSTR) (iType!=0 ? TEXT (" ") : szKeyName),
                                 (TCHAR) (iType ? pmsg[i].wParam : ' '),
                                 LOWORD (pmsg[i].lParam),
                                 HIWORD (pmsg[i].lParam) & 0xFF,
                                0x01000000 & pmsg[i].lParam ? szYes  : szNo,,// for extended key flag

                                 0x20000000 & pmsg[i].lParam ? szYes  : szNo,
                                 0x40000000 & pmsg[i].lParam ? szDown : szUp,//Previous key state
                                 0x80000000 & pmsg[i].lParam ? szUp   : szDown)) ;//transition state
              }
              EndPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;
              return 0 ;

         case WM_DESTROY:
              PostQuitMessage (0) ;
              return 0 ;
         }
         return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam) ;
    }
```

My problem is that I can't understand the code.I tried my best .

In the line

> static TCHAR * szFormat[2] = {
>
> ```
>                TEXT ("%-13s %3d %-15s%c%6u %4d %3s %3s %4s %4s"),
>                TEXT ("%-13s            0x%04X%1s%c %6u %4d %3s %3s %4s %4s") } ;
> ```

what is happening ?I understood the first line but not the second one.

in TextOut function

what does   `szMessage [pmsg[i].message - WM_KEYFIRST],` 
means
and what  the codes used
 `0x01000000`
and why we used specifically  &0XFF with    `HIWORD (pmsg[i].lParam) & 0xFF,`

I know these are lot of questions but none of them were explained in the book .Please could anyone answer atleast one of the questions.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Just a comment, I don't really know windows programming but it *sure* must have changed a lot since 1998. I mean it wasn't even NT kernel at the time lol. Maybe you should consider investing in a textbook from this era.

Comment: @Jean It really hasn't, at least not the basics. Petzold's [Programming Windows, 5th Edition](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Windows%C2%AE-Edition-Microsoft-Series/dp/157231995X) is still the standard textbook. Copyright date 1998.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In the line
>
> ```
> static TCHAR * szFormat[2] = {                
>              TEXT ("%-13s %3d %-15s%c%6u %4d %3s %3s %4s %4s"),
>              TEXT ("%-13s            0x%04X%1s%c %6u %4d %3s %3s %4s %4s") } ;
> ```
>
> what is happening? I understood the first line but not the second one.

This is not really Windows-specific. It is just an array of C-style strings, which are themselves pointers to a nul-terminated array of characters.

- It is declared `static` so that it is only initialized once when the function is first called, and maintains its value across subsequent calls.
- `TCHAR` is a Windows typedef for either `char` or `wchar_t`, depending on whether or not you're building a Unicode application. So `TCHAR *` is equivalent to either `char *` or `wchar_t *`.
- The name `szFormat` is [systems hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation#Systems_vs._Apps_Hungarian), common in Win32 programming and used extensively by Petzold. The `sz` means it is a nul (**z**ero)-terminated **s**tring.
- The `[2]` part just makes it an array that contains two elements. An array that itself contains arrays.
- `TEXT` is a function-like macro that is used to declare string literals appropriately, depending on the build configuration. In Unicode builds, an `L` is appended to the beginning of the string literal to make it a wide string. In non-Unicode builds, nothing is appended.
- The strings themselves are just format strings, like you might use with the [`printf` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html) in standard C. Except that Petzold's code is using it with [`wsprintf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647550.aspx), the Windows version of this C function. Basically, all of the `%` parts are *placeholders* that are filled in with the values of variables you specify. They have special decorations to provide more extensive control over the formatting of the output string.

> ```
> case WM_SIZE:
>
>        if (message == WM_SIZE)
>        {
>              cxClient = LOWORD (lParam) ;
>              cyClient = HIWORD (lParam) ;
>         }
> ```
>
> What does `message == WM_SIZE` mean?

I have no idea. That looks like a bug to me, actually. Inside of the `WM_SIZE` case, you already *know* that `message` is `WM_SIZE`. It is therefore pointless to check it again. Just pretend it isn't there.

> what does `szMessage [pmsg[i].message - WM_KEYFIRST],` mean?

From the name and the variable declaration at the top, you know that `szMessage` is an array of C-style strings, just like we saw with `szFormat`. It contains the names of the window messages he's interested in, like `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP`.

The stuff in brackets is an indexer into the array. It is just as if he had written `szMessage[1]` to access the second element in the array, except he's calculating the index of the item to be accessed dynamically using an expression.

The expression is built so that it matches the message name in the array up with the message ID known at runtime. You get the message ID from `pmsg[i].message`, and then subtract it from `WM_KEYFIRST` because that is the ID of the first keyboard message. That makes the message ID sync up the order of the message names in the string array.

> and what  the codes used `0x01000000`
>   and why we used specifically  &0XFF with    `HIWORD (pmsg[i].lParam) & 0xFF,`

Those are just bit masks. Combining them with a bit value using the `&` operator (bitwise AND) masks off the specified bits.

As for their meaning, that is all covered in the documentation for the particular window message. For example, in the [`WM_KEYDOWN` docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280.aspx), it tells you the meaning of specific bits in the `lParam` value. By masking off those bits, you can isolate them to get at the individual pieces of data.

Petzold is taking advantage of the fact that all of the keyboard-related messages he's monitoring (listed in the `szMessage` array we just talked about) all use the same formatting for the `lParam` value. This is verifiable by looking at the respective documentation for each of those messages. For example, [`WM_CHAR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646276.aspx) is the same as we just saw for `WM_KEYDOWN`. That allows the code to be vastly simplified.

The purpose for this, of course, is to display this information about keyboard events to the user each time the window gets painted.

Comment: "It is declared static because it is only to be used within the code file in which it is defined—i.e., it does not have external linkage." Linkage is irrelevant to local variables (names of..) AFAIK.

Comment: @DyP Err, oops. I assumed it was a global variable. Missed the fact that it was local. Fixing...

Comment: "An array that itself contains arrays." It's an array of pointers, it arguably *contains* arrays.

Comment: I agree with u that there is no need of WM_SIZE==message,because when I removed the if statement then still the code worked correctly

Comment: but what is x and X in TEXT ("%-13s            0x%04X%1s%c %6u %4d %3s %3s %4s %4s") } ;

Comment: The `x` indicates that the number should be displayed in hexadecimal format. An uppercase `X` means that the hexadecimal value should be upper-cased (e.g. `0x00A03F`).